# Правильно ли я понимаю, что надо писать «фигня вопрос»?

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли я понимаю, что надо писать *фигня вопрос* (не *фигня-вопрос*), т. к. здесь *фигня* — это как прилагательное, имеющие значение *ничегошный*?

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=264#pp264

Comment: В смысле прилагательное?  https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/фигня, https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/шайтан-труба. Вы наверное имели в виду "определение", а не прилагательное. Типа галстук бабочкой, галстук-бабочка

Comment: фигня вопрос = не вопрос, фигня - вроде отрицательной частицы.